# how to end the quiz once three questions are answered wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

Once the player has three questions wrong my game continues instead of stopping, what do I add/change to make the program stop once three questions are answered incorrectly. I have included a while loop in the program, have I not done this properly?

```
print ("Note: you must answer using A, B, C or D")
print (" ")

lives = 3
print ("lives =", lives)
print (" ")

name = input ("What is your name?")
print ("Hello",name,". Good Luck.")


while lives != 0:
    ##is the player ready to start
    play = input ("Would you like to start? (Type Y for yes and N for no)")
    if play == "Y" or play == "y":
        from time import sleep
        sleep (1.0)
        print("Starting in...")
        sleep (1.0)
        print("3")
        sleep(1.0)
        print("2")
        sleep(1.0)
        print("1")
        break
    ##3, 2, 1 countdown added wk.4 friday
    elif play == "N" or play == "n":
        print ("End")
        break
    else:
        print ("That is not an answer.\n")


## 1st Question
question1 = ("1. What is Brisbanes AFL team called?")
options1 = (" a. Brisbane Tigers \n b. Brisbane Lions \n c. Brisbane Broncos \n d. Brisbane Magpies")
print (question1)
print (options1)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "B" or answer == "b":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives=lives-1


## 2nd Question
question2 = ("2. What sport did Greg Inglis play")
options2 = (" a. rugby league \n b. rugby union \n c. AFL \n d. Soccer")
print (question2)
print (options2)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "A" or answer == "a":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives=lives-1
## 3rd Question
question3 = ("3. Where were the 2018 Commonwealth Games held?")
options3 = (" a. Sunshine Coast \n b. Melbourne \n c. Brsbane\n d. Gold coast")
print (question3)
print (options3)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "D" or answer == "d":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives=lives-1


## 4th Question
question4 = ("4. How many players in a netball team can shoot?")
options4 = (" a. 1 \n b. 2 \n c. 3\n d. 4")
print (question4)
print (options4)
answer = input (">")
if answer == "B" or answer == "b":
    print ("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
    print ("lives =", lives - 1)
    lives=lives-1
```

The game continues when 3 questions are answered wrong instead of stopping. MY quiz contains 20 questions but I have attached 4 so you are able to see the problem better.  Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Comment: The code you posted is working without any issues, can you explain where the error is coming @lex

Comment: I would like to add a lives feature. so the player starts with three lives and after a question is answered wrong they loose a life. when three lives are wrong the game will end. I have tried addin these codes but they didn't work or maybe I added them to the wrong place?

Comment: Please update the full code along with what you tried for implementing the `lives` scenarion @lex

Comment: I mean add the combined code of what you tried for your lives scenario, not two separate piece like you have @lex

Comment: I don't see you using `lives` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Here a working full code:

```
from time import sleep

# List that saves questions and answers as in: (question, options, answer)
QUESTIONS = [
  ("1. What is Brisbanes AFL team called?", " a. Brisbane Tigers \n b. Brisbane Lions \n c. Brisbane Broncos \n d. Brisbane Magpies", "B"),
  ("2. What sport did Greg Inglis play", " a. rugby league \n b. rugby union \n c. AFL \n d. Soccer", "A"),
  ("3. Where were the 2018 Commonwealth Games held?", " a. Sunshine Coast \n b. Melbourne \n c. Brsbane\n d. Gold coast", "D"),
  ("4. How many players in a netball team can shoot?", " a. 1 \n b. 2 \n c. 3\n d. 4", "B")
]

print("Note: you must answer using A, B, C or D")
name = input("What is your name? ")
print(f"Hello {name}. Good Luck.")

def answer_question(question, options, correct_answer):
  """ Returns True if the input is correct; False, otherwise"""
  print(question)
  print(options)
  answer = input("> ")
  if answer.upper() == correct_answer:
      print("Correct!")
      return True
  print("Incorrect.")
  return False

def start_quiz():
  """
  Start quiz with full lives.
  Returns True when the game is over, if either the user won or it
  does not want to keep playing; returns False otherwise.
  """
  lives = 3
  print(f"You have {lives} lives.")
  ##is the player ready to start
  while True:
    play = input("Would you like to start? (Type Y for yes and N for no) ")
    if play.upper() == "Y":
      sleep (1.0)
      print("Starting in...")
      sleep (1.0)
      print("3")
      sleep(1.0)
      print("2")
      sleep(1.0)
      print("1")
      break
    ##3, 2, 1 countdown added wk.4 friday
    elif play.upper() == "N":
        print (f"Goodbye, {name}!")
        return True
    print ("That is not an answer.\n")

  for question, options, answer in QUESTIONS:
    if not answer_question(question, options, answer):
      lives=lives-1
    if lives == 0:
      print("You are out of lives!\nGAME OVER\n")
      return False
  print(f"{name}, you have answered all questions correctly.\nCONGRATULATIONS!\n")
  return True

# Runs the quiz until someone wins or the user is not ready
while True:
  result = start_quiz()
  if result:
    break
```

I saved your questions and answers in a list, like that you just iterate over the list and you do not have to duplicate code for each question (with the prints and lives check).

If you have any more questions, don't hesitate!